# Trying to share objects between classes which need to be declared at the same time

Tags: java, object

Currently I have the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GUI gui = new GUI();
    Server server = new Server(gui);
    server.startServer();
}
```

in one of my classes called Server.java

However, I need to access a method in the Server.java class from inside the GUI.java class - I don't know how to pass the server object to the GUI class because the GUI needs to be created to pass it to the server object, but the server needs to be created to pass it to the gui class.

So ideally I would want:

```
GUI gui = new GUI(server);
Server server = new Server(gui);
```

but of course this can't happen.

Comment: Use a setter to set it after construction.

Comment: Could you add a `setGUI(GUI)` to your `Server`, and/or a `setServer(Server)` to your `GUI`?

Comment: This design is a bit suspicious, if you ask me.

Comment: Thanks, the setter works:) @FedericoklezCulloca why do you say so?

Comment: Because I don't like circular dependencies :)

Answer (score 0):

A clean solution would be to use an `Interface`:

```
public interface ServerMethods {
    void shutdownServer();
}
```

Now you can use a setter in your `GUI`:

```
public class GUI {
    public void setServerMethods(ServerMethods sm) {}
}
```

And if you now implement the `Interface` in your `Server` its a clear design:

```
public class Server implements ServerMethods {
    ...
}
```

Now you have a clear interface and no circular dependency.